# React - Django page is blank on refresh

Tags: python, reactjs, django, url, routes

Hello I am using Django as my backend and React as frontend. I have an issue when I refresh page and I am not on root page `'/'` the page goes blank. Also If Ill try to go instantly somewhere else then the home page such as `/contact` it is blank also. I know it is because the backend server was not contacted as it is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually). I tried to fix it with `useHistory` but it did not work showing useContext error.
What is the best way to fix this issue with Django - React stack?

main urls.py:

```
    urlpatterns = [
       ...
       path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
    ]
```

app urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('frontpage', FrontpageViewSet, 'frontpage')
router.register('gallery', GalleryViewSet, 'gallery')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

React index.js:

```
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js:

```
const location = useLocation();
return (
    <div className="App">
        <GlobalStyle/>
        <Nav/>
        <Switch location={location} key={location.pathname}>
            <Route exact path='/'>
                <HomePage/>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/gallery'>
                <GalleryPage/>
            </Route>
            <Route exact path='/contact'>
                <ContactPage/>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by putting useHistory to all pages and loading it with useEffect when the page loads.

Comment: How did you connect  react with django rest framework?

Comment: With django rest framework you create REST API endpoints. Then you just sending requests to that API enpoints. You can try google some tutorials like this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-connect-django-with-reactjs/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re_path` instead of `path` in your main `urls.py`. Don’t forget to import it also:

```
from django.urls import include, re_path
```